# Dictionary.get: Dictionary does not contain key: bucketMeans Error when trying to apply Otsu threshold

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, landsat

I am trying to apply Otsu's threshold to remove water from my NDVI image. But when running the code I get the error:

> ImageCollection (Error)
> Error in map(ID=1_2_LE07_020039_20220510):
> Dictionary.get: Dictionary does not contain key: bucketMeans.

The image shows nothing when I try to display the image with Map.addLayer, so they probably have null. I am wondering if there's anyway to filter them out so that I don't get the error. Or any other idea would be helpful.

```js
var PEI = 
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-88.64042172041307, 30.446701603950796],
          [-88.64042172041307, 30.32290398952697],
          [-88.49004635420214, 30.32290398952697],
          [-88.49004635420214, 30.446701603950796]]], null, false);

          
Map.centerObject(PEI, 15)


var otsu = function(histogram) {
  var counts = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(histogram).get('histogram'));
  var means = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(histogram).get('bucketMeans'));
  var size = means.length().get([0]);
  var total = counts.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
  var sum = means.multiply(counts).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
  var mean = sum.divide(total);
  
  var indices = ee.List.sequence(1, size);
  
  // Compute between sum of squares, where each mean partitions the data.
  var bss = indices.map(function(i) {
    var aCounts = counts.slice(0, 0, i);
    var aCount = aCounts.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
    var aMeans = means.slice(0, 0, i);
    var aMean = aMeans.multiply(aCounts)
        .reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0])
        .divide(aCount);
    var bCount = total.subtract(aCount);
    var bMean = sum.subtract(aCount.multiply(aMean)).divide(bCount);
    return aCount.multiply(aMean.subtract(mean).pow(2)).add(
           bCount.multiply(bMean.subtract(mean).pow(2)));
  });
  
  //print(ui.Chart.array.values(ee.Array(bss), 0, means));
  
  // Return the mean value corresponding to the maximum BSS.
  return means.sort(bss).get([-1]);
};

var threshold_func = function(image) {
  image = ee.Image(image).select('NDVI')
  var histogram = image.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram()
      .combine('mean', null, true)
      .combine('variance', null, true), 
  geometry: PEI, 
  scale: 10,
  bestEffort: true
  });
  
  var threshold = otsu(histogram.get('NDVI_histogram'));

  var water_removed = image.gt(threshold).selfMask();
  return water_removed;
};



var addNDVI = function(img) {
    var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4']).rename('NDVI')
    return img.addBands(ndvi)
}

var addNDVIpre8 = function(img) {
    var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['B4','B3']).rename('NDVI')
    return img.addBands(ndvi)
}

var landsat5 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_TOA").filterBounds(PEI)
          .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 20)
          .select(['B5', 'B4', 'B3', 'QA_PIXEL'])
          .map(addNDVIpre8)
print('l5', landsat5)

var landsat7 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_TOA").filterBounds(PEI)
          .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 20)
          .select(['B5', 'B4', 'B3', 'QA_PIXEL'])
          .map(addNDVIpre8)
print('l7', landsat7)

var landsat8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA").filterBounds(PEI)
                    .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than',20)
                    .select(['B5', 'B4', 'B3', 'QA_PIXEL'])
                    .map(addNDVI)
print('l8', landsat8)   

var landsat = landsat5.merge(landsat7).merge(landsat8)
print('total', landsat)



//var landsatlist = landsat.toList(landsat.size());

var landsat_otsu = landsat.map(threshold_func)
print(landsat_otsu)
```

Link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/46a1c8ed3b8ae773fea005a65ac87576

Answer (score 0):

The `filterBounds` function returns every image where the image's footprint intersects your ROI, even if there are no valid pixels in the ROI.  And the `reduceRegion` function will return null when there's no pixels in the request.

So... you need to decide what you want to do about images that only partially intersect your ROI.

You can either: filter images that don't contain the entire ROI via:

```
.filter(ee.Filter.contains(".geo", PEI))
```

or you can provide a default value in the `get()` call that presents a properly structured, but "empty" histogram.